# Generate a new color without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, dom

I have to refresh the page every time I want to generate a new color with the button, versus pressing the button to generate a new color.

```js
let hexBtn = document.querySelector('button');

let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
let letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];

let hex = numbers.concat(letters);

let array = [];
```

Loop through the array and randomize the element order, then push to new empty array.

```js
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  let random = hex.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
  array.push(random[i]);
}


function hexColor() {
  let joinArray = array.join("");
  let hash = '#'
  let color = hash.concat(joinArray);
  console.log(color);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

hexBtn.addEventListener('click', hexColor);
```

Comment: Avoid putting lengthy sentences in titles. They should be short and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to simplify your code because you have only one color generated at the loading page. You can generate your color in the `hexColor()` function:

> *A color is 3 value between 0 and 255 (RGB), you can generate a random number between 0 and 255*255*255.
>
> Now, you can just convert your decimal random number into hexadecimal by using [Number.toString([base])](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Number/toString) and add the `'#'` before.*

```js
let hexBtn = document.querySelector('button');

function hexColor() {
  let color_rgb = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(255*255*255));
  let color_hex = '#'.concat(color_rgb.toString(16));
  console.log(color_hex);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color_hex;
}

hexBtn.addEventListener('click', hexColor);
```

```html
<html>
  <head><title>Button color</title></head>
  <body>
    <button>Generate hex</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But what if I wanted to use the Hex Color instead of RGB?

Comment: @tydangelo18, Hexadecimal color is just a way to use the same value but shorter. All the possible values in hexa (from `#000000` to `#ffffff`) are the same that the RGB system (from `rgb(0,0,0) = 0` to `rgb(255,255,255) = 16581375`)

Answer (score 0):

thibsc answer has correct and more efficient way to generate random number then your example, but let me tell you why your example does not work.

`hexColor` function is what is attached as on click event handler of the `hexButton` button, and what this function does now is only formatting random numbers to create hex color code and then sets it as page background.

Color does not changes because your randomized data is done at page load, the array that contains random numbers and the loop that generates random numbers and puts them into array are outside of the `hexColor` function attached to the button.

You need to put them inside the function so every time you press the button random numbers will be generated again so color will change.

```
let hexBtn = document.querySelector('button');

let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
let letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];

let hex = numbers.concat(letters);

function hexColor() {
  let array = [];

  //Loop through the array and randomize the element order, then push to new empty array.    
  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    let random = hex.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
    array.push(random[i]);
  }    

  let joinArray = array.join("");
  let hash = '#'
  let color = hash.concat(joinArray);
  console.log(color);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

hexBtn.addEventListener('click', hexColor);
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I'm still very new to JS, but I am always looking for more efficient ways to write code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let hexBtn = document.createElement("button");
hexBtn.textContent = "cool"
hexBtn.style = "position:fixed; top: 0; z-index:999999";

let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
let letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];

let hex = numbers.concat(letters);

let array = [];


function hexColor() {
  console.log(array)
  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    let random = hex.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
    array.push(random[i]);
  }
  let joinArray = array.join("");
  let hash = '#'
  let color = hash.concat(joinArray);
  console.log(color);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  array=[];
}
document.body.appendChild(hexBtn);

hexBtn.setAttribute("onclick","hexColor()");
```

```html
<html>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```